# Home security system recommendation

Tags: security, alarm

I want to purchase a DIY wireless home security system. 
For the moment, I do not want to pay a home monitoring service and prefer to be informed of my alarm status via the Internet (WiFi and cellular) and text messages.

The main entrance to the house is a [steel gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjCCM.jpg). Not sure if a sensor exists for this type of entrance. I have 3 solid wood doors, 1 aluminum door with window, many [aluminum horizontal louver style windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjXwY.jpg) and a couple of [glass horizontal louver style windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVkp1.jpg).

Also, I have an indoor cat.

I wanted some input on what types of alarm systems and sensors you guys recommend for this setup to work and I can install.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Iris](http://www.lowes.com/cd_Iris_239939199_). You can mix and match components such as door/window sensors, thermostats, motion sensors, etc. It hooks to your wifi and can send you text alerts.